# emacs inside of tmux inside of putty on windows does not seem control keys

Tags: emacs, putty, tmux

I've been search around and it seems there is no one who's concerned about my specific problem. Following is some configurations:

```
PuTTY Release 0.70
Keyboard: Function keys ESC[n~
Window/Colours, allow xterm 256 color
Connection/Data, terminal-type string xterm-256color

$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

I believe I've followed most useful looking answers here but it's still not working. The issues are two:

1. The Ctrl + arrow keys are not work fine, ONLY in emacs
2. Ctrl + ,(comma) and .(period) is entirely not responding, as if the keys were not pressed, for all of outside of tmux, inside of tmux, and inside of emacs inside of tmux.

For the first point, it seems like Emacs is acting up, because I can indeed see difference by pressing Ctrl + v in terminal:

```
$ ^[[A
$ ^[OA
```

For the second one, I have no clue. I am wondering if anyone has dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have experienced, `Emacs` works best in GUI mode. I would suggest, you install a Xserver, such as Xming: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

Then you can start `Emacs` in your putty session, and `Emacs` will be opened with its native GUI.

Comment: nice thank you. i will try it once i have access to my windows machine again.